# redirect through .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have made one file say a.php. Now I want some thing like if one tries to open a.php then He should ne redirected to another page of same directory of site.

I want it throght .htaccess file.
I have written this code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
Redirect /b.php /a.php
```

both pages are stored in same directory..

Comment: did you intentionally left out the the redirect flags? like [R=301,L] etc.

Comment: I dont anything about it .. can you elaborate it?

Comment: That will mean that you lack the basic knowledge about .htaccess and its usage. Why not refer to the link provided by @Arvind Sridharan provided in his answer. Better yet let us know more with examples, what you wish to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /a\.php /otherfile.php [R=301,L]
```

Change the filenames were necessary. 
If you could be more specific as to what you wish to achieve,perhaps I can supply you with a better solution.

Question that might help:

- Is it only for the file a.php, or there are other request that will be handled the same way as this pattern?

Hope it helps!

Comment: brother .. still it is not working properly.. what i want is if one opens specific file ib browser say a.php.it should be redirected to another page in same directory.

Comment: I am developing it in localhost. just want to learn about .htaccess

Comment: I get the general idea about what you are trying to achieve here. There are many ways to solve the issue and enough knowledge about the problem will help us all to give the best solution. I am saying this because a regular expression could be used if the redirection follows a pattern, or if the file being acccessed is inside a sub directory under the server root, or if the redirection will consider query strings. If these sounds advanced or confusing, please state in codes, what you actually tried and failed. 

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Please refere to the link below. I think so it will help you out.

[How do I redirect my site using a .htaccess file?](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use this if your script has a request string.
Like you want to stay on the same page, but not to show a request string.

(in case you want to post or get some data through scripts)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/path/to/a/([0-9]+) /path/to/a.php?foot=$1 [PT]
```

Also, you should consult with the link Codemaster Gabriel and Arvind Sridharan gave you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use header function in order to redirect..
try this

inside a.php
type:-

```
    <?php
    header ('location: b.php'); //lets say b.php is the file you want to redirect
    ?>
```

it will work..
and it is recommended to use this instead of .htaccess due to security reason of apache

Comment: While this will work, the OP is trying to learn how to do redirection with .htaccess.  I don't see any reason that this is better than letting Apache manage redirection, and I challenge you to maintain a list of 500 redirects by creating php files with header() instead of a single .htaccess file with all the redirects or even a couple of rules to handle them all.